# SQL Transaction Error Handling

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Do you guys see any problems with the way I handle errors in the following stored procedure? I am still not confident enough with SQL to realize if I am doing anything wrong. Thank you :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserAccounts_Create]
    @username varchar(255),
    @email varchar(255),
    @password nvarchar(127),
    @id bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @now smalldatetime
    SET @now = GETDATE()

    DECLARE @userId bigint
    DECLARE @transactionSuccess bit
    SET @transactionSuccess = 0

    BEGIN TRANSACTION       
        INSERT INTO UserAccounts([username], [email], [password], [createDate], [lastLoginDate])
            VALUES (@username, @email, @password, @now, @now)

        SET @userId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        INSERT INTO Users([id], [firstName], [lastName])
            VALUES (@userId, '', '')

        SET @transactionSuccess = 1;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    IF (@transactionSuccess = 1)
        RETURN 0; -- Success.
    ELSE
        RETURN 1; -- Some unknown error occured.
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hit an error that causes you to abort, `RETURN 1;` will never happen.

Instead of using that syntax, why not try out the new(ish)

```
BEGIN TRY
...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
...
END CATCH
```

syntax?  It gives you much more control, and is (IMO) a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you have a look at [TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

Using this you can *BEGIN TRANSACTION* and *COMMIT TRANSACTION*, or *ROLLBACK* in the event of an error.